# Excel Macro to compare two dates if two columns have specific text in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to write an Excel macro which does;
1. Check column A for a specific value
2. If column A has a specific value (text), than search column B for another text value in the same row.
3. If column B also has what we are looking for, then compare the dates in Column C and D for that specific rows. (Column A and B have the specific text in the same row)

Basically macro will search all rows of a sheet. If two columns have what we are looking for and if this happens in the same row, than compare two dates.

```
`If (COLA = val1) & (COLB = valb) Then;
     If COLC < COLD Then;
       Color the row to Red
     Else if COLC >= COLD Then;
       Color the row to Green
     Else
       Color the row to Yellow
     End If
Else 
     Color the row to Brown
End If`
```

---

|COLA |COLB |   COLC    |   COLD    |
|val1 |vala |11.12.2018 |20.12.2018 |
|val1 |valb |10.10.2018 |20.12.2018 |
|val2 |vala |01.01.2019 |15.02.2019 |
|val3 |valc |24.02.2019 |11.02.2019 |
|val2 |vald |30.12.2018 |20.12.2018 |

**Example Table**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub valsAndDates()
    With Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A:D")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=and($a1=""vala"", $b1=""vala"", $c1<$d1, $c1<>text(,))")
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
          Formula1:="=and($a1=""vala"", $b1=""vala"", $c1>=$d1, $c1<>text(,))")
            .Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However it gives "invalid procedure call" error with the following line: "With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
 Formula1:="=and($a1=""val1"", $b1=""vala"", $c1<$d1, $c1<>text(,))")"

Comment: I don't know where that trailing `"` came from but it obviously doesn't belong.